# Blazor EditContext with weird behavior when triggering OnFieldChanged event

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am facing a really strange weird behavior with a single blazor page. I have a main blazor page that has few custom components inside it. One of this components has its own EditContext and Model associated to it.
Also in that component I have few formulas that I need to calculate whenever the value in the fields changed. To do so, I have added an event listener for OnFieldChanged.
For some reason I can't find out, sometimes the event is fired when some of internal component variable is changed and the model passed as parameter for the event, is the Component itself, instead of my context model. Meaning it is fired when a local variable is changed instead of a model field.

It is not happening at first time component is rendered. As it goes and calculate formulas every time any field value is changed, after 3 or 4 calculations it starts happening.

That is causing an infinite loop, because when formula value is changed it is firing the event that recalculate the formulas and fire the event again.

It was not really supposed to fire the event when an internal formula value changes.

Also I have attached a Debug screenshot.

Please take a look on my piece of code:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@_editContextProduct" style="margin:0px">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    //ALL MY FIELDS HERE
</EditForm >

@code{
private CommercialEvaluationProductContextModel _commercialEvaluationProductContextModel = new ();

private EditContext _editContextProduct;

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
        _editContextProduct = new EditContext(_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel);
        _editContextProduct.OnFieldChanged += ProductEditContext_OnFieldChanged;
}

//formulas declaration
private int _formulaPacksPerStore =0;
private decimal _formulaSizeofPrice =0;
private decimal _formulaRetailerMargin =0;
private decimal _formulaRevenue =0;
private decimal _formulaMargin =0;
private decimal _formulaCogs =0;
private int _formulaPacksPerRun = 0;
private int _formulaProductionFrequency = 0;
private decimal _formulaCogsPerPack = 0;

 private void ProductEditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender,FieldChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        DoCalculateFormulas();
 }


private async void DoCalculateFormulas()
    {
        _formulaPacksPerStore = _commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ExpectedAnnualPackVolume /
                        Math.Max(1,_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ListingDuration) /
                        Math.Max(1,_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.DistributionValue);

        _formulaSizeofPrice = _commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.RetailSalePrice * _commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ExpectedAnnualPackVolume;

        _formulaRetailerMargin = _formulaSizeofPrice * (_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.RetailerMargin / 100.0M);

        _formulaRevenue = _formulaSizeofPrice - _formulaRetailerMargin;

        _formulaMargin = _formulaRevenue * (_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.Margin/100.0M);

        _formulaCogs = _formulaRevenue - _formulaMargin;

        _formulaPacksPerRun = _commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ExpectedAnnualPackVolume / Math.Max(1,_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ListingDuration);

        _formulaProductionFrequency = 365/Math.Max(1,_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ListingDuration);

        _formulaCogsPerPack = _formulaKepakCogs / Math.Max(1,_commercialEvaluationProductContextModel.ExpectedAnnualPackVolume);

    }
}
public class CommercialEvaluationProductContextModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(maximumLength: 200, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } 


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose the product state")]
        [Range(1, 99900, ErrorMessage = "Invalid product state")]
        public Int16 ProductStateId { get; set; }
        
        public ProductState? ProductState { get; set; }


        [Range(1, 99900, ErrorMessage = "Choose the listing type")]
        public Int16 ListingTypeId { get; set; }
        
        public ListingType? ListingType { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 99900, ErrorMessage = "Choose duration of listing")]
        public Int16 ListingTimeIntervalId { get; set; }
        
        public TimeInterval? TimeInterval { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inform duration of listing")]
        [Range(1, 9999999, ErrorMessage = "Invalid duration of listing")]
        public int ListingDuration { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 32000, ErrorMessage = "Invalid distribution")]
        public Int16 DistributionTypeId { get; set; }
        public DistributionType? DistributionType { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inform the distribution value")]
        [Range(1, 99999999, ErrorMessage = "Invalid duration of listing")]
        public int DistributionValue { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inform the expected annual pack volume")]
        [Range(1, 99999999, ErrorMessage = "Invalid expected annual pack volume")]
        public int ExpectedAnnualPackVolume { get; set; }


        [Range(1, 99999, ErrorMessage = "Invalid currency")]
        public Int16 CurrencyId { get; set; }

        public Currency? Currency { get; set; }

        [Range(typeof(decimal), "0.1", "99999999999.99", ErrorMessage = "Invalid retail sales price")]
        public decimal RetailSalePrice { get; set; }

      [Range(typeof(decimal), "0.1", "99999999999.99", ErrorMessage = "Invalid margin")]
        public decimal Margin{ get; set; }
        [Range(typeof(decimal), "0.1", "99999999999.99", ErrorMessage = "Invalid retail margin")]
        public decimal RetailerMargin { get; set; }


        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimum of 3 characters")]
        public string SalesRational { get; set; }

        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimum of 3 characters")]
        public string CategoryRational { get; set; }


        [Range(1, 99900, ErrorMessage = "Invalid expected annual pack volume")]
        public Int16 EstimatedProductWeightMeasureUnitId { get; set; }
        public MeasureUnit? MeasureUnit { get; set; }

        [Range(typeof(decimal), "0.1", "99999999999.99", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Estimated Product Weight")]
        public decimal EstimatedProductWeight { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 99900, ErrorMessage = "Invalid expected annual pack volume")]
        public int NumberPouchesperInner { get; set; }


        public string StatusId { get; set; }
     
    }
```

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu1EN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always bind a control to a property not a field.

Comment: I can consider this answer as solved, although I took a different approach. I am now comparing the editContext Model type with the fieldIdentifier argument when event is raised. If they are different I know it was the formula field instead of entity property. Thanks @navid